# adding emails with diffrent scope to the same distribution group on exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

i have an exchange server 2007 installed on windows sbs 2008, i want to create distribution group and assign emails to it,but these emails have diffrent scope like

(asd@yahoo.com , qwe@hotmail.com  , zxc@asd.com ......and so.)

can i do it 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange only allows Active Directory objects to be part of any distribution group. For every external email address you want to add, you will have to add an external contact to Active Directory.